# How to access raw nv21 frame using native camera class in Android L?

Tags: android, android-camera

We are trying to create a native camera application which will process nv21 data for Android L. We are using Camera class from the path: /frameworks/av/include/camera/Camera.h in source code. We have registered startRecording function with CameraRecordingProxyListener.

In ProxyListener::dataCallbackTimestamp(nsecs_t timestamp, int32_t msgType, const sp& dataPtr) we are getting dataPtr, but using this dataPtr we are not getting raw buffer, the size is also fixed which is 20.

Since onPreviewFrame on Java Application is giving us correct raw buffers, which will internally use Native Camera APIs. So there must be a way to get raw buffers in callback using some interface. Which native interface does Android Java Camera APIs uses internally and how to get raw buffer using this interface.

Please help us with the above issue as soon as possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be better off having a little bit of Java code that forwards buffers to native NDK code. Using non-public native classes and methods is not portable across devices or releases.